# Fold/Unfold with single shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is possible to fold/unfold with the same shortcut key in VSCode?

I was searching at the github and have found this:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/18549

The last comment in this issue:

> I added a new shortcut Ctrl + K Ctrl + K

Current `ctrl+k ctrl+k`:
[image]

When I press it nothing happens. Does someone else know anything about it?

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
I have found an option that does it, follow:

[image]